# Adding a title prepared as "Standard" into the TOC in Lyx

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, horizontal-alignment, lyx

In LyX, I want to center a title for my "Chapter One". However, using the Automatic sectioning i.e. "part" for example can only have the section title left aligned. I chose "Standard" so I can manipulate the paragraph to center align. It however can't appear on the TOC. Please assist. Document class used is Article(Standard Class).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you post the LaTeX source of a small example that shows your current approach?

Comment: I am using Lyx, which is a Latex editor. Much of it is similar to MS Word where commands are simply "drop-down-menu" based. I have not used any "codes" so to speak.

Comment: However, to shed more light, in developing a document, I would wish to have a Table of Contents. Each section more or less appear in the TOC list. The default style of each paragraph can be selected on a drop-down-menu on the tool bar. I however do not want the "uneditable" left aligning of section headers. Using a standard option  of the paragraph so as to centre the header renders the section header not included in the TOC. What should I do to ensure I add this content on the TOC?

Comment: The closest I came to help was from (https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/TOC) option 4.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a **Part** for setting your section, use **Section** and add the following to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\bfseries\centering}
```

The font setting above are the default associated with the [`article` class](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co).

While the visual inside LyX won't display the sections as being centered

[image]

the output will:

[image]

If you want it to show inside LyX as well, you can add the following Document > Settings... > Local Layout:

```
Format 60

Style Section
  LatexType    Command
  LatexName    sect1
  InnerTag     "title"
  CommandDepth 2
  Align        Center
End

Style Section*
    CopyStyle  Section
    Margin     Static
    LatexName  bridgehead
    LatexType  Paragraph
    InnerTag   "!-- --"
    LabelType  No_Label
    ResetArgs  1
    LatexParam renderas="sect1"
End
```

This results in the following display in LyX:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. This helps but what should I do to have say "Chapter One" and not "1. Chapter One"? If I use the sectioning options with * "asterisks" the number disappears but the subsection numbering is altered. I want to maintain numbering for subsection but have no number preceding the section such that "introduction" after "Chapter One" would read "1.1. Introduction" and so on for other subsections. Thanks you.

Comment: I am a new user of Stackexchange with no idea on how to attach a screen shot for better elaboration.

Comment: @GeorgeKariuki: That's doable inside LaTeX, which means you can place some stuff in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. However, I'm not sure how to change that on the display side of LyX. That is, things may still print the way you see them in the image above, but your output to PDF will show as you want it. Would that be okay?

Comment: Yes that would be ok. I know how to work in the lyx preamble though I don't know which package to use so as I get the output as I put it.

Comment: @GeorgeKariuki: See if adding `\let\oldsection\section \renewcommand{\section}{\refstepcounter{section}\oldsection*}` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble solves your problem (in the resulting PDF).